# Cocos2d-x Game screen not fit in iPhone 4 with iOS 7

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am new for Cocos2d-x, I found strange issue in my game we are testing in all simulator that working fine. also we are testing our game in iPhone 5 and iPad all thing working perfect but got an issue in only iPhone 4 device. there is game screen display small and there are show top and right side black area like following screenshot:

[image]

I check its all Default images size and resolution is correct as par apple guide line.

Can you please suggest me how to fix this issue. i can't figure it out is there any code related issue or something need to change in xcode.

Following is iPhone 5 screen shot:

[image]

---

Here is my appdelegate code:

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()
{
    wrapper->authenticateLocalPlayer();
    // initialize director
    CCDirector *pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    pDirector->setOpenGLView(CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView());
    pDirector->setOpenGLView(CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView());
    // turn on display FPS

    pDirector->setDisplayStats(false);

    // set FPS. the default value is 1.0/60 if you don't call this
    pDirector->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 60);
    CCSize Size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

    IPADX = Size.width/1024;
    IPADY = Size.height/768;

    if (Size.width==1024 || Size.width==2048){
        CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->setDesignResolutionSize(1024, 768, kResolutionExactFit);
        SCALEX = 1.0f;
        SCALEY = 1.0f;
    }
    else
    {

            if (Size.width<568)
            {
                SCALEX = 960.0f/1024;
                SCALEY = 640.0f/768;

            }
            else
            {
                SCALEX = 1136.0f/1024;
                SCALEY = 640.0f/768;

            }
    }

        // create a scene. it's an autorelease object
    CCScene *pScene = HelloWorld::scene();

    // run
    pDirector->runWithScene(pScene);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your setup code?

Comment: Are you using any `DesignResolutionSize` for glView ? Look Appdelegate.

Comment: Yes i used setDesignResolutionSize i edit my question please check @VijayMasiwal and iphonic

Comment: @NitinGohel You have not set any resolution for iPhone 4, it should be `640x960`

Comment: Can you please edit my code and put your answer i will impliment and let you know @iphonic

Comment: Just add ` CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->setDesignResolutionSize(960, 640, kResolutionExactFit);` in else condition by checking the size

Comment: @iphonic let me check

Comment: there is right side still show black area @iphonic top screen is now fit

Comment: Try `ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER` instead of kResolutionExactFit

Comment: sorry but same output with NO_BORDER

Comment: @LearnCocos2D can you please check once

Comment: Check this http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support

Comment: check this already and used this same :(

Comment: maybe [my old answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90405/cocos2d-x-supporting-multi-resolution-using-density-independent-pixels/90406#90406) give you some clue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

//set design resolution

```
 Size designSize = Size(960, 640);
    if (Size.width==1024 || Size.width==2048){
        designSize = Size(1024, 768);
        SCALEX = 1.0f;
        SCALEY = 1.0f;
    }
    else
    {

        if (Size.width<568)
        {
            SCALEX = 960.0f/1024;
            SCALEY = 640.0f/768;

        }
        else
        {
            SCALEX = 1136.0f/1024;
            SCALEY = 640.0f/768;
            designSize = Size(1136, 640);
        }
    }

    CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->setDesignResolutionSize(designSize.width, designSize.height, kResolutionExactFit);

    CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->setContentScaleFactor(MAX(768/designSize.height,1024/designSize.width) );
```

Comment: I used your code that hight issue solve but right side still show black area

Comment: After add scaleFact got crash with `Assertion failed: (m_eResolutionPolicy == kResolutionUnKnown), function setContentScaleFactor,`

Comment: @NitinGohel What is version of cocos2d-x no you are using?

Comment: try this line `Director::getInstance()->getOpenGLView()->setContentScaleFactor(MAX(768/designSize.height,1024/designSize.width) );`

Comment: its 2.1.4 version and i used the line you said but application crashed i mention in above comment assertion failed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77865/discussion-between-vijay-masiwal-and-nitin-gohel).